# How to set play button on image hover state?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have created popup play youtube videos using `html,css and jquery.`

Now i need to show, play button when hover an image.

Here is my code tried,

http://jsfiddle.net/495vbwy2/

May i know, how to do?

Html:

```
  <div class="videoThum"> <a href="javascript:;"  rel="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GNb8T5NBdQg?list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810" class="youTubeVideo" ><img src="slide-2.jpg"/></a></div>
</div>
```

When i worked out like this ,

```
.guideBox .videoThum a:hover{color:#000; opacity:1;}
```

It doesn't work. May i know, how to do this,

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/495vbwy2/4/

Comment: half of your css is redundant, you should clean it up

Answer (score 0):

try this. change color and opacity according to need.

```
.youTubeVideo:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url('image.png');
}
```

Comment: i tried like this .videoThum img:hover {
background:url('images.jpg'); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

 
} but, when an hover, image play button didn't display.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="videoThum"><a href="javascript:;"  rel="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GNb8T5NBdQg?list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810" class="youTubeVideo" ><img src="slide-2.jpg"/><span class="icon"></span></a></div>
```

CSS

```
.videoThum .youTubeVideo {
    position: relative;
}
.videoThum .youTubeVideo .icon {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; // Set icon position you want
    left: 50px; // Set icon position you want
}
.videoThum .youTubeVideo:hover {
    display: block;
}
```